# Check if parameter exists in Expression Language

Tags: jsp, parameters, jstl, el

```
<c:if test="${param.username}" >
</c:if>
```

How do I check if param.username exists??

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use the `not empty` check.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.username}" >
</c:if>
```

Edit: If you have a parameter of the form `?username` (no value), it is safer to use `${param.username ne null}`

Comment: What if `host/?parameter`. It exists but is empty.

Comment: I have just tested in my Java EE 6 environment Servlet 3.0 and it DOES NOT work:

`page/?fail` -> does it exists? yes, the parameter exists.
`${ not empty param.fail }` -> `false`

Comment: This answer should not be getting upvoted. "domain.com/login?fail" produces produce a param ("fail") that does exist, but is empty.

Answer (score 49):

If you want to check if parameter exists, just test if it is not null, in your case:

```
<c:if test="${param.username != null}"></c:if>
```

#### Broader explanation:

If you want to check:

- if yourParam exists/ is not null:

  `<c:if test="${param.yourParam != null}"></c:if>`
- if yourParam does not exist/ is null

  `<c:if test="${param.yourParam == null}"></c:if>`
- if yourParam is not empty (not empty string and not null)

  `<c:if test="${!empty param.yourParam}"></c:if>`
- if yourParam is empty (empty string or null)

  `<c:if test="${empty param.yourParam}"></c:if>`
- if yourParam evaluates to 'true'

  `<c:if test="${yourParam}"></c:if>`
- if yourParam evaluates to 'false' (string other than 'true')

  `<c:if test="${!yourParam}"></c:if>`

Comment: Nice answer showing all possible options and how they operate.

Answer (score 6):

If I may add a comment...

To test if the request parameter "username" does not exist in the JSP page "a-jsp.jsp", we can write an "if" clause in the page "a-jsp.jsp":

```
<c:if test="${empty param['username']>
...
</c:if>
```

We'll go through that "if" clause if the requested URL is:

`http://server/webapp/a-jsp.jsp`

or

`http://server/webapp/a-jsp.jsp?username=`

We won't if the requested URL is:

`http://server/webapp/a-jsp.jsp?username=foo`